# Problem upgrading after trying to install wireguard in Devuan Chinera

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, wireguard, devuan

Trying to install wireguard / wireguard-tools on a Raspberry Pi3b running Devuan Chimaera.

Get blocked in generating the system images --- see below:

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-rt-arm64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64
 linux-image-rt-arm64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@there:~# dpkg --configure linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64
Setting up linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64 (5.10.205-2) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.10.0-27-rt-arm64:.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64
Creating initrd.gz.
cp: target '/boot/initrd.gz': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//99-initrd exited with return code 1
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64
```

--- This after several runs through, tried after using `apt-get satisfy`, or `dpkg --configure`.  I end up with the trace above or similar - but always failing to build `linux-image-5.10.0-27-rt-arm64`

I eventually will just rebuild but I'd hate to have to reinstall all the stuff on that little box :-(

Thanks!

Comment: I fail to see a relation between WireGuard and a kernel update/installation error. WireGuard is part of the shipped kernel and doesn't require anything special to be present (that could have been the case in older kernels, but not with 5.10).

Comment: What is the result of `df -T /boot/` (with trailing slash)?

Comment: root@there:~# df -T /boot/

Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
                                         
/dev/mmcblk0p1 vfat    261868 210760     51108  81% /boot

Comment: Can't tell. Maybe initrd.gz is a symlink but before this the /boot filesystem went full and its target was removed. Anyway again, no relation with WireGuard.

Answer (score 0):

OP - Found the problem!

I was out of space on /boot, apparently.  Removed two Kernel copies (which were not deleted using 'autoremove'), and after two 'apt -y upgrade' got what looked like a completion (no errors or warnings on the second time).  And, Hallelujah, it is functional and can reboot.

Thanks for your help, all.